# Azure App service zip deploy failure that used to work (Legacy react app)

Tags: reactjs, azure, appservice, zipdeploy

I am trying to redeploy a legacy react application via Zip Deploy. The application hasn't changed, but the deployment is now failing. I reverted to a previous deployment zip (that was successfully deploy in November 2022) and it fails with the same error message. Here is the error trace:

```
1:39:11 PM diningmanagermobile-dev: Creating zip package...
1:39:13 PM diningmanagermobile-dev: Zip package size: 3.35 MB
1:39:15 PM diningmanagermobile-dev: Updating submodules.
1:39:15 PM diningmanagermobile-dev: Preparing deployment for commit id '0866cdcc18'.
1:39:16 PM diningmanagermobile-dev: Generating deployment script.
1:39:16 PM diningmanagermobile-dev: Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted" -o "C:\home\site\deployments\tools" --basic --sitePath "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted"'.
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev: C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\296456~1.8
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev: odejs\build\src\Loader.js:153
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:                 ...StatusLogger.DEFAULT_STATUS,
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:                 ^^^
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:     at module.js:669:12
1:39:17 PM diningmanagermobile-dev:     at Array.forEach (native)

Any ideas what could have changed on the Azure App Service Zip Deploy?
```

Comment: I got it working. The WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION application setting was set to an older Node version. This worked previously, but I am guessing that the older Node version was no longer available and the ZIPDeploy deployment scripts must be relying on a newer version.

I updated it in the app setting and now everything it working with the ZipDeploy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it working. The WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION application setting was set to an older Node version. This worked previously, but I am guessing that the older Node version was no longer available and the ZIPDeploy deployment scripts must be relying on a newer version. I updated it in the app setting and now everything it working with the ZipDeploy.

Comment: this also worked for me though my app does not use node.js

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue. What' s the exact Node version that works for both of you? Also @Fai

Comment: I used 10.15.2. hth.

Comment: @Vanderwood ~16

Comment: @Vanderwood "~18" (written like that, without quotes) works as of this writing.

Comment: Man, I'm glad you figured this one out. This is not a very intuitive error message to receive. I updated that web app setting to 18 and everything is now working. Thanks!

Comment: I checked WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION setting was enabled, deleted it and then retriggered the deployment and it worked

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who can't get Tim's solution to work in a .NET app on a windows-latest pipeline spec. What worked for me was setting the agent spec to windows-2022 instead of windows-latest

Edit: I can't speak for other types of applications/specs but from my experience this does not affect deploying to a Linux Container App Service Plan or Azure Funtions